# Tabbing to first Google result

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-search

I'm using Chrome 16.0.912.77 on Windows 7, with the Vimium plugin for Chrome.

I prefer to navigate my browser with the keyboard as much as possible. A really useful feature of Chrome was that I could type a search string in the address bar, and then hit tab to iterate through the results.

This behaviour has changed recently - now, hitting tab first moves to the Google+ links (the black bar at the top) and then down the sidebar, before getting to the search results.

On my Macbook (OS X 10.7, newest version of Chrome) I still have the old, desired behaviour.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: any solution to this?  Too bad they changed this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was moved to the DOWN arrow key when searching from the Chrome address bar.

TAB still works, but you need be searching using an already loaded google search page, and you need to have instant results turned on.

Answer (score -1):

Keyboard navigation of Google Search results is available as long as Google Instant is available. As you type in your search query, Google Instant will suggest popular queries. Once you have typed in the appropriate text, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image: Google Instant Search]

Once the results are displayed, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go through the results. You should see a small arrow to the left of the result that is being selected. Simply hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to the selected search result.

[image: Google search results navigation]

### Note

This answer has been tested on Mozilla and Google Chrome on Windows 7. There is a possibility that extensions that modify Chrome's default behaviour, such as *Vimium*, may interfere with keyboard navigation. Try disabling these extensions and use Google Instant Search again.

Further information on Google search results navigation can be [found here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/191139?hl=en).

> When you search with  Google Instant turned on, not only do you see
>   results as you type, but you can also navigate your search results
>   quickly using keyboard shortcuts. Let’s say you need a new coffee
>   table, so you start searching for coffee t. When the predictive text
>   for coffee table appears, press Tab to complete the query, then Enter,
>   then Tab to select the first result. Use the up arrow and down arrow
>   keys to jump from result to result and then press Enter to open the
>   webpage of the result you’ve selected.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Chrome on Ubuntu and none of the solutions I found was working for you so i have created my own. You need [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) and then just create new user script and paste in following code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Google-tab to search results
// @include  https://www.google.*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
$(".g .r a").attr( 'tabindex',1);
```

It adds `tabindex="1"` to all search results so you can tab trough all the results from first to last. To open selected link use one of the keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Enter</kbd> loads page in same tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> loads in new background tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> loads in new foreground tab
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> loads in new window